# python: elegant way of finding the GPS coordinates of a circle around a certain GPS location

Tags: python, dictionary, math, gps, coordinates

I have a set of GPS coordinates in decimal notation, and I'm looking for a way to find the coordinates in a circle with variable radius around each location.

[Here is an example](http://green-and-energy.com/downloads/test_circle.html) of what I need. It is a circle with `1km` radius around the coordinate `47,11`.

What I need is the **algorithm for finding the coordinates of the circle**, so I can use it in my kml file using a polygon. Ideally for python.

Comment: Interesting question. You will probably get an answer much more quickly at http://gis.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the formula for "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point" here:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

with your centre point as start point, your radius as distance, and loop over a number of bearings from 0 degrees to 360 degrees. That will give you the points on a circle, and will work at the poles because it uses great circles everywhere.

Comment: I think this is it. Thanks for the link. It is difficult to search for such things if you don't exactly know how it's called... This is why I love this site and you all. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

see also [Adding distance to a GPS coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839533/adding-distance-to-a-gps-coordinate/2839560) for simple relations between lat/lon and short-range distances.

this works:

```
import math

# inputs
radius = 1000.0 # m - the following code is an approximation that stays reasonably accurate for distances < 100km
centerLat = 30.0 # latitude of circle center, decimal degrees
centerLon = -100.0 # Longitude of circle center, decimal degrees

# parameters
N = 10 # number of discrete sample points to be generated along the circle

# generate points
circlePoints = []
for k in xrange(N):
    # compute
    angle = math.pi*2*k/N
    dx = radius*math.cos(angle)
    dy = radius*math.sin(angle)
    point = {}
    point['lat']=centerLat + (180/math.pi)*(dy/6378137)
    point['lon']=centerLon + (180/math.pi)*(dx/6378137)/math.cos(centerLat*math.pi/180)
    # add to list
    circlePoints.append(point)

print circlePoints
```

Comment: Nice. Is this stable near the poles?

Comment: No, this approximation is very practical but as you can see there is a 1/cos(lat) term, so it diverges at the poles. Also it is only accurate for relative distances below 10-100km.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple trigonometry problem.

Set your coordinate system XOY at your circle centre. Start from `y = 0` and find your `x` value with `x = r`. Then just rotate your radius around origin by angle `a` (in radians). You can find the coordinates of your next point on the circle with `Xi = r * cos(a)`, `Yi = r * sin(a)`. Repeat the last `2 * Pi / a` times.

That's all.

**UPDATE**

Taking the comment of @poolie into account, the problem can be solved in the following way (assuming the Earth being the right sphere). Consider a cross section of the Earth with its largest diameter `D` through our point (call it `L`). The diameter of 1 km length of our circle then becomes a chord (call it `AB`) of the Earth cross section circle. So, the length of the arc `AB` becomes `(AB) = D * Theta`, where `Theta = 2 * sin(|AB| / 2)`. Further, it is easy to find all other dimensions.

[image]

Comment: That is correct for a Cartesian, rectilinear xy system. But, lat/long is not such a system. It approximates one for small offsets and near the equator. But over long distances the lines curve, and they converge at the poles.

Comment: @poolie yes, this is not my topic. But for the small circle of 1 km radius it may work quite well. Otherwise, you can try spherical CS but it is more complex then.