# How to get a new gps coordinate at a known distance that lies between a known start and end gps coordinate?

Tags: android, python, google-maps, gps

I am working on google maps api + python code, And i'm kinda stuck with a doubt. I basically have 2 gps co-ordinates, start and end point, and i am able to calculate the shortest distance between them using the ideas i got from stackoverflow. for example lets say the distance between (x1,y1) & (x2,-y2) is 100 meters. Now the next task is to get a list of coordinates which is lying on the same path between start & end point 10 metres apart(which basically would be 9 more coordinates coz the 10th will be the end point which i already know). I can apply ratio calculation and get a (x,y) out but keeping the earth's spherical structure in mind is there any other algorithm, theorem, package or solution you'd recommend? I'd appreciate any thoughts that you'd like to share. thanks.

also will the solution mentioned in this link work? [Adding distance to a GPS coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839533/adding-distance-to-a-gps-coordinate)

Answer (score 0):

Albert Einstein - "I am thankful to all those who said no. It's because of them, I did it myself."

to solve a problem like the one I was facing above, we can simply implement a ration calculation that will give a very accurate output.

(x1-x2)/(x1-x)=100/10

x=?

solve this equation for x & similarly for y and we'll find the coordinates.