# How can i set rectangle size in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm creating rectangle using coordinates with Google Map.

I want to set its size to 75 meter(width & height equal to 75).

This is My code :

```
function initialize() { 

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 20,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.626805, -89.539396),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({ 
    strokeColor: 'green',
    strokeOpacity: 12,   
    strokeWeight: 12,     
    fillColor: 'green',  
    fillOpacity: 12,    
    map: map,   
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.626805, -89.539396),
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.626055, -89.538507))   
    });     

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cnuu7rtL/4/

Please Tell me How can i set rectangle size in google map?

Comment: The rectangle size is cofigured using the `bounds` object.  You will have to make an initial coordinate and then add the distance or `size` you want to make the closing coordinate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839533/adding-distance-to-a-gps-coordinate

Comment: i think link you posted is related to android.i need this in javascript in google map as you can see my code.

Comment: Yes, it is however the theory is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a desired center  of the rectangle(it's possible too with other points like southwest, northeast, etc.):

Use the [geometry-library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) to calculate the distances from the given center to create the bounds.

Sample-function:

```
function calcBounds(center, size) {
    var n = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, size.height/2, 0).lat(),
    s = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, size.height/2, 180).lat(),
    e = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, size.width/2, 90).lng(),
    w = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, size.width/2, 270).lng();
    return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(s,w),
                                          new google.maps.LatLng(n,e))
}
```

Usage:

```
new google.maps.Rectangle({bounds:calcBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(40.626805, 
                                                                    -89.539396),
                                             new google.maps.Size(75,75)),
                           map:map});
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/cnuu7rtL/7/**](http://jsfiddle.net/cnuu7rtL/7/)

Comment: Dr.Molle ,But,your code is creating problem,because i have approx 600 grid boxes,it show only 1 with your code,can you explain reason why?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the code. Example with 600 rectangles: http://jsfiddle.net/cnuu7rtL/10/

Comment: actually var rectangle is in my foreach loop and im using this code  in rectangle:   bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.626805, -89.539396),
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.626055, -89.538507)), ,you can check here this code is same as my original code  http://jsfiddle.net/cnuu7rtL/11/

Comment: There are 2 rectangles, but they are placed at the same position, so one rectangle will cover the other rectangle. When you make them transparent you will see both: http://jsfiddle.net/cnuu7rtL/14/

Comment: i think   var map = is creating problem ,this is not in foreach loop.and your   function calcBounds(center,size) is taking same center,am i right ??

Comment: `calcBounds` will use the center that has been passed as argument, when you always pass the center of the map it will always use this point. Example using the center of your given LatLngBounds instead: http://jsfiddle.net/0c9rnyf8/ (I've added some markers because the rectangles are hard to find at higher zoom-levels)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60445/discussion-between-mr7-itsurdeveloper-and-dr-molle).

Comment: can we drew line between these two center points without Markers?in your example http://jsfiddle.net/0c9rnyf8/

Comment: Actually, i have multiple boxes and when I implement lines are drwan like this
http://jsfiddle.net/0c9rnyf8/2/
Is it possible to draw a line within boxes from point to point.??