# Matlab GPS + distance in meters

Tags: matlab, gps

I have to calculate for a given Latitude (lat0) and Longitude (lon0) the new latitude (lat1) and longitude (lon1) if I move a distance x[m] and y[m] away from the initial position. For example:

```
clear all; clc;
%initial coordinates:
lat0=56;
lon0=5;

%moving away from lat0,lon0,
xcor=200; %[m]
ycor=100; %[m]
```

First I use this code to calculate lat1 and lon1: (source: [Adding distance to a GPS coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839533/adding-distance-to-a-gps-coordinate))

```
lat1=lat0+rad2deg((xcor/6372800))
lon1=lon0+rad2deg((ycor/6372800)/(cos(lat0)))
distance=sqrt(xcor^2+ycor^2)
```

Now i want to check my answer with the haversine equation:

```
dlat = deg2rad(lat1-lat0);
dlon = deg2rad(lon1-lon0);
lat0 = deg2rad(lat0);
lat1 = deg2rad(lat1);
a = (sin(dlat./2)).^2 + cos(lat0) .* cos(lat1) .* (sin(dlon./2)).^2;
c = 2 .* asin(sqrt(a));
distance_check=6372800*c
```

However, most of the time the distance from haversine is different with 100+ meters compared to the calculated distance in the first 3 lines of code.

What is going wrong in this code?

Comment: The site http://www8.nau.edu/cvm/latlongdist.html gives the same answer as the haversine equation... That means the error has to be in the first initial calculation?

Comment: I have found the error myself. In the first code, 2nd line, cos(lat0) has to be cos(deg2rad(lat0)). I hope this post will help some people in the future :)

Comment: Maybe use `cosd(lat0)` instead of `cos(lat0)`? Edit: 35 seconds late :P

Comment: @JurriënPlijter: When you found the answer yourself, please write an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code, 2nd line, `cos(lat0)` has to be `cos(deg2rad(lat0))`.