# How can I add X distance to the west (or north or east or north) to coordiates?

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

I want to add X distance to the west (or north or east or north) to coordinates.

I get coordinates like this :

```
        LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();                   
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

             longitude = loc.getLongitude();
             latitude  = loc.getLatitude();
             altitude  = loc.getAltitude();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    }
```

I find set mock location like this:

```
try { 
                    Location mockLocation = new Location(provider); // a string
                    mockLocation.setLatitude(latitude);  // double 
                    mockLocation.setLongitude(longitude); 
                    mockLocation.setAltitude(altitude);  
                    mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    mockLocation.setAccuracy( Float.parseFloat("20"));
                    mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());

                    locationManager_mock.addTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                            false, false, false, false, true, true, true,
                            Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

                    locationManager_mock.setTestProviderLocation(provider, mockLocation); 
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                             toastt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

But I do not want to add 20 meters to west or somewhere?

thanks in advance.

### I FOUND MY SOLUTION :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38424087/1332870

Comment: I ve seen that question but I cant understand how can I set location to 20 meters left acn you explain

Comment: @gabe-sechan can you explain how?

Comment: THe dupe has 2 equations in the accepted answer.  Use them

Comment: they are not my answer. I want to add 10 meter to the just to the west(this is optional) from my coordinates.

Comment: That it your answer.  Use the equation.  Adding distance in GPS location is actually complex, as the longitude depends on the latitude.

Comment: but ı do not want to 100 meters around my coordinate. I want to 100 meter to the west or east or north okey

Comment: And the equations let you do that.  If you don't know how to use an algebraic equation then you need to study math.

Comment: can u easily show how can I use that? thanks in advance