# Create coordinate based on distance and direction

Tags: algorithm, gps, coordinates, distance, latitude-longitude

So i have coordinate (A) with x longitude and y latitude. What i want is create new coordinate (B) where distance (meter) between both of coordinate and direction (0 - 360) based on user input. What formula to achieve that?

so far what i do is use this formula from [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477003/calculating-new-longtitude-latitude-from-old-n-meters) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839533/adding-distance-to-a-gps-coordinate)

```
new_latitude  = latitude  + (dy / r_earth) * (180 / pi);
new_longitude = longitude + (dx / r_earth) * (180 / pi) / cos(latitude * pi/180);
```

but it just create new coordinate with one direction, what i want is direction can be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use formula from [this excellent site](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) (section Destination point given distance and bearing from start point)

```
var φ2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                    Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
var λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(φ1),
                         Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2));
```

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, θ is the bearing (clockwise from north), δ is the angular distance d/R; d being the distance travelled, R the earth’s radius